# FFMPEG ignoring attempts to set user agent or other headers

Tags: ffmpeg, user-agent

I am on Windows, using the latest build from Zeranoe which was linked on the ffmpeg site.

My command is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -headers 'User-Agent: "This does not Work"' -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto  -i "local.m3u8" -c copy "out.mp4" -v trace
```

My local.m3u8 file is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.000,
http://127.0.0.1/
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

On localhost I have a simple server running that logs the user agent. It outputs:

```
{ 'user-agent': 'Lavf/58.29.100',
  accept: '*/*',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  'icy-metadata': '1' }
```

The user agent has not been set. I have tried using -user-agent "test" and -user_agent "test" instead of -header, and have tried putting the arguments in a different order, no success.
The trace Output of -v trace is https://pastebin.com/raw/W9hsjraT

Why is the User Agent not being overwritten, and how can I overwrite it?

Comment: As the log shows, the shell has split the token after `User-Agent:`. Go with `-user_agent "Your string"`

Comment: Have tried that already as said, no success.

Comment: It works here, if I access the m3u8 over http.

Comment: Ah yup, it seems that it only sends the changed User Agent for the .ts file requests if i access the m3u8 via http/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that FFMPEG only sends the custom headers if the input m3u8 is accessed via http/s, not if it is a local file.
Thanks @Gyan for this.